# $(document).open() not working under these circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize in advance if this has been asked before. So the circumstances I mentioned in the title is this:

I am writing html into a new window.document.open() object. The html I am writing also includes  in the head. 
This is the script I am not able to run,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       alert('This is working!');
     });
</script>
```

The interesting thing is that every other jquery code works. For example in my html I have a button with id='but' and this script works

```
 $('#but').click(function(){
     alert('you clicked a button')'
   });
```

so why is the $(document).ready() not working? Is this because window.document.open() doesn't count as document for jquery?

Thanks in advance.

edit: I think my question is unclear. I am terribly sorry about that. Here's the situation: 
I have a javascript file that essentially has this:

```
    var w=window.open();
                    var temp=`
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <title> Template for converted files</title>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
                        <script>
                               $(document).ready(function(){
               alert('This is working!');
             });
                        </script>
                    </head>
                    <body class="body">
                     <button id='but'>click me!</button>
    </body>
    </html?
                    `;
                    w.document.open();
                    w.document.write(temp);
```

the file file.js has the following:

```
$('#but').click(function(){
     alert('you clicked a button')'
   });
```

now when I run the first JS file, I am able to open a new window with the button. when clicked it says "you clicked a new button" 
But the alert "This is working!", isn't working.

Hope this makes the situation clear. I am really sorry for not being clear from the start.

Comment: Your code does not include document.open. more code needed..

Comment: create a fiddle example of your problem so that we can check and rectify it

Comment: if you dont know jquery exact list of methods look here : http://api.jquery.com

Comment: My problem has two separate javascript files. One js file deals with writing the html page into a separate w.document.open() object, another javascript file which is linked the html written onto w.document.open() object has the jquery scripts I mentioned in my problem. 
I don't know how to create a fiddle for this situation.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more details :)

Answer (score 3):

Because jQuery has no method `open()` in it's api.

`open()` is a `window` method only.

You can refer to the new window by passing it to a variable:

```
var win = window.open(url[,options])
```

Comment: I have two separate JS files. One JS file writes html into window.document.open() object. This html has the script I mentioned in the question. 
So how do I refer to this window in the situation?